# return specific view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I have a controller at ~/Controllers/MyController.cs and a view ~/Views/My/V1.ascx . How can I return view V1.ascx in a controller's ReturnV1 method? I tried:

```
return View("V1");
```

but it returns an empty response instead of my view.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? It throws an error saying it can't find the view?

Comment: Without extra information, we can only guess as to what the problem is.

Comment: It returns an empty response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view is user control (ascx) file but should be aspx.

Comment: It is supposed to be ascx, I should not change it.

Comment: Yeah. In that case, you should follow M4N

Comment: No I think he meant calling parent view of that partial view.

Comment: return View("whatever-parent-view-name");

Comment: How do I find out the parent view?

Comment: That's a good question you need to ask yourself. What is the reason you made the page ascx. You must have some page embedding this ascx because that ascx is only for embedding. Otherwise, you gotta make it aspx or create a aspx page embedding that partial view.

Comment: I am returning some HTML code for an AJAX request. In my project problems like this are all solved returning a View based on ascx control.

Comment: You didn't say that in your description, did you? If you are using ajax, that's whole different story. Please post your ajax statement and controller.

Comment: It appeared that the request was wrong, not the server code. Strange.

Comment: @Bogdan0x400 I am glad that you resolved the issue, but would you mind sharing your resolution in your original question. It will help others who have the same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to use `PartialView("V1")` instead of `View("V1")` (since the view is called `V1.ascx`)?

Or do you have another (empty) view named `V1.aspx` in the same folder? In that case, this will have precedence over the ascx View.

Comment: I've tried calling PartialView also, still returns nothing, and no exceptions are thrown. I also don't have any other views with same name.